# Check stored procedure, if it is valid

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have problem in my program and I didn't find error in my code. I think it's because StopProc. Can anybody check my stored procedure to see if it is valid?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Update_FeatureUsers 
    (
        @FeatureID int,
        @UserID nvarchar (MAX),
        @CreatedUserID int
    )

AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    Declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar (400)
    Declare @Query nvarchar(MAX)

    SET @Query = N''
    SET @Query = @Query + N'DELETE FeatureUsers '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'FROM FeatureUsers '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'WHERE FeatureUsers.FeatureID = @FeatureID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'    AND FeatureUsers.UserID NOT IN ('+ @UserID +')'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query

    SET @Query = N''
    SET @Query = @Query + N'INSERT INTO FeatureUsers (FeatureID, UserID, CreatedUserID) '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'SELECT @FeatureID, Usager.UserID, @CreatedUserID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'FROM Usager WITH (NOLOCK) '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'WHERE Usager.UserID IN ('+ @UserID +') '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'    AND Usager.UserID NOT IN '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'    ( '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'        SELECT FeatureUsers.UserID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'        FROM FeatureUsers WITH (NOLOCK) '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'        WHERE FeatureUsers.UserID IN ('+ @UserID +') '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'            AND FeatureUsers.FeatureID = @FeatureID '
    SET @Query = @Query + N'    ) '

    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@FeatureID int '
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, @FeatureID = @FeatureID

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    RETURN
```

Comment: When i call this storproc, it not do modifications in database!!! Sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: You mean, what's wrong with it *besides* the SQL Injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first dynamic SQL query also wants to access `@FeatureID`, but you're not passing it.

So move:

```
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@FeatureID int '
```

Up to the top of the proc and then call

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query,@ParmDefinition,@FeatureID = @FeatureID
```

for **both** pieces of dynamic SQL.

---

For the general strategy - it would be far better if you made the stored proc accept a table-valued parameter for `@Users` and then you wouldn't need to use dynamic SQL at all.

---

Actually, on second reading, your second query also references `@CreatedUserID`, so you'll need to pass that across as a parameter to the second query. So you need to change the parameter definition between the two, or just add it to the parameters and pass it (pointlessly) to the first query.

Comment: And if the client doesn't support table value parameters, you can pass xml

Comment: Wow, good idea for future! Now it work! Tnx (ps. i'm beginner in programming)